# create textbox column in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

This is my code:

```
 Private Sub BindGrid()
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn(2) {New DataColumn("Id", GetType(Integer)), New DataColumn("Name", GetType(String)), New DataColumn("Country", GetType(String))})
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States")
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India")
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France")
    dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia")
    dt.Rows.Add(5, "Name", "abc")

    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()

    dt.Rows.Add(dr)

    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

I want to add another blank text box column where I can write something and save it in the database. How do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [TemplateField.EditItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.edititemtemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Expr">

    <EditItemTemplate>    
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Bind("FieldName") %>'></asp:TextBox>    
    </EditItemTemplate>   

</asp:TemplateField>
```

Have a look at [Using TemplateFields in the GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx)